# vector::reserve ran into read access violation when working with Vulkan API

Tags: c++, c++20

`C++20` CODE
Has to be C++20 cuz I've written some template in C++20
No `C++20` no compile
Comp. with VS 2022
Happens when in Debug conf.
Don't happen when in Release conf.
Without debugger it still happen.

A exception was thrown in which:

```
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Orphan_range_unlocked(pointer _First, pointer _Last) const {
    _Iterator_base12** _Pnext = &_Mypair._Myval2._Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
    while (*_Pnext) {
-----------^^^^^^^
        const auto _Pnextptr = static_cast<const_iterator&>(**_Pnext)._Ptr;
        if (_Pnextptr < _First || _Last < _Pnextptr) { // skip the iterator
            const auto _Temp = *_Pnext; // TRANSITION, VSO-1269037
            _Pnext           = &_Temp->_Mynextiter;
        } else { // orphan the iterator
            const auto _Temp = *_Pnext; // TRANSITION, VSO-1269037
            _Temp->_Myproxy  = nullptr;
            *_Pnext          = _Temp->_Mynextiter;
        }
    }
}
```

where

`_Mypair._Myval2._Myproxy is nullptr`

The popup window reads:

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0x8.
```

My code was:

```
struct Swapchain 
{
    struct SwapchainImage
    {
        VkImage img;
        VkImageView view;
        VkFramebuffer frame;

        ImageDepthTest depth;

        SwapchainImage(VkDevice device, VkImage image, const VkExtent2D& extent, VkFormat depth_format, VkSurfaceFormatKHR surface, VkRenderPass pass, const VkAllocationCallbacks* alloc = nullptr);
        inline SwapchainImage(SwapchainImage&& e) noexcept : img(e.img), view(e.view), frame(e.frame), depth(std::move(e.depth)) { e.img = nullptr; e.view = nullptr; e.frame = nullptr; }
        SwapchainImage(const SwapchainImage&) = delete;
        ~SwapchainImage() noexcept;
    };
    std::vector<SwapchainImage> imgs;
    ...
}
```

```
vkResult = BUG_CHECK(vkCreateSwapchainKHR, device, &createInfo, alloc, &this->swapchain);

this->depth_format = FindDepthFormat(phys);

uint32_t nSize = 0;
BUG_CHECK(vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR, device, this->swapchain, &nSize, nullptr);
std::vector<VkImage> vkImages(nSize);

this->imgs.reserve(nSize); // without this, everything is fine, nSize = 3 btw

BUG_CHECK(vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR, device, this->swapchain, &nSize, vkImages.data());
for (auto e : vkImages)
{
this->imgs.emplace_back(device, e, this->extent, this->depth_format, format, pass, alloc);
}
```

In my opinion, the `reserve` function shouldn't matter.
However I got this problem even though I tweaked my code:
simply making the constructor of `this->imgs[*]` do nothing.

The `this->imgs` is empty before reserve btw.
Don't know how could this happen.
I recalled that long ago I have written code like this with Vulkan API it ran into the same problem.

I understand that I can totally remove the reserve and everything will work.
But I want to know why is this code incompatible with Vulkan API, and typically swapchain related.
I can't represent this under simple situations such as `std::vector<int>;` // LMAO I texted ';' instead of '.', nice one!

Comment: `// without this, everything is fine, nSize = 3 btw` -- Which indicates that your program has a bug somewhere elese.  Adding or removing lines that should have no effect is a clear indication of memory corruption occuring elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was because I called the destructor beforehand.
The vector can be directly reused no problem after destruction if I don't call reserve.
Thank PaulMcKenzie's comment.
I will modify my code to prevent calling vector::~vector before using it.